# How to prove the binomial theorem

Tags: probability, binomial-theorem

I'm trying to prove the following:

$$ (p + q)^n = \sum_{x=1}^n \frac{n!}{x!(n-x)!}p^xq^{n-x}. $$

But I'm not sure where to start, would expanding the left hand side get me anywhere?

Any tips or hints to prove this ?

Comment: You could try induction. Suppose this is true for n and write the sentence for n+1 as a product. Then apply the formula for n and expand...

Comment: This identity is known as the binomial theorem. Using a search engine you can find zillions of proofs. You can also find a proof on Wikipedia.

Comment: Prove that it's true for the first $n$ of the series. Suppose it's true for $n$, then multiply both sides of the equation by $p+q$. We will deduct that the series is also true for $n+1$.

Answer (score 1):

As Rodrigo Ribeiro said, you could try induction. Note that the following result will be useful:

$\binom{n}{k} + \binom{n}{k-1}$ = $\binom{n+1}{k}$

which can be proven algebraically.